Image disappears in .exe of WinUI application
I've managed to make my WinUI3 application singlefile and in one exe, unpackaged.
When I run in VS, images show up properly, however, when I run the exe, the images disappear. Would love for advice.
Also only images which disappear are ones which are locally stored. Windows icons work as expected.
<Ellipse Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,60,0,0">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/SrkYocOB_400x400.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>


Can you confirm that the jpg file is in the Asset folder, and that the Asset folder and the exe file are on the same folder?

can confirm, however found a solution so will post

There was 2 things preventing the images from being shown.
The first was to do with unpackaged WinUI3 applications. The paths have to be dynamically calculated based on the executable's location.
This can be done by adding the following in the backend:
string exeFolder = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
string imagePath = Path.Combine(exeFolder, "Assets", "your_image.png");
yourImageControl.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));

Secondly, the build action of images have to be set properly.
1.Locate your image files in the Solution Explorer.
2.Right-click each image file and select Properties.
3.Ensure that the "Build Action" is set to Content.
4.Ensure that "Copy to Output Directory" is set to Copy if newer or Copy always.
